# TinyMCE 4 Ignores HTML Formatting For Outlook

Tags: outlook, tinymce-4

When I try to use an HTML source for an email template, for some reason TinyMCE ignores all the tags that are supposed to prepare the email body to be rendered properly in Outlook desktop. An example of the mentioned tags is: `<!--[if !mso]>...`

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has run into the same problem, the solution that worked for me was to add `allow_conditional_comments: true` to the options of the TinyMCE control.